# Embeddings of curves and an intrinsic description of the normal bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Assume we have a smooth algebraic curve $C$ over complex numbers. Consider then all possible embeddings of $C$ into a smooth algebraic surface $X$.

Here are two questions:

1) How many are there different such embeddings for fixed $C$ and $X$?
(in moduli-theoretic sense)

(I understand that this must heavily depend on $X$: type, algebraic structure etc.
as well as on $C$).

2) Is there a way to characterize the divisor classes on $C$ corresponding to normal bundles of $C$ for various such embeddings?

Here $X$ is still fixed. A generalized version of this question for $C$ fixed and $X$ varying in the moduli space of the type to which $X$ belongs is partially answered by Sasha below, where he chose $X$ to vary in the class of geometrically ruled surfaces.

Comment: For any line bundle $L$ on $C$ you can embed $C$ into $P_C(O \oplus L)$ as a section in such a way that the normal bundle is $L$, so the normal bundle can be arbitrary.

Comment: Sasha, thank you. This is elementary, of course, but somehow I was not able to get it at the moment of writing my comment.

Comment: N B and @Sasha: I thought the problem was for _fixed_ $C$ and $X$? Those projective bundles certainly won't be isomorphic for all $L$...

Comment: Artie, thank you. I apologize for not formulating it clearly. Actually, Sasha answered the version of the question stated in parentheses which allows to vary $X$ (he chose $X$ to be geometrically ruled). When one fixes $X$, it is still not answered here.

Comment: By the way, Sasha, I think your argument gives the answer for the divisors of the same degree, this is when you vary the algebraic structure of $X$, while topologically $X$ is the same. One can do it for every fixed degree in this way, of course.

Comment: @N B: Not quite. For example, if $C = P^1$ then $X = P_{P^1}(O \oplus O(k))$ is a Hirzebruch surface, and as far as I understand those for even $k$ and for odd $k$ are not homeomorhpic.

Comment: Sasha, of course you are right, by proceeding in this way for every fixed degree I didn't mean that $X$ stays unchanged topologically. So that for different degrees we have topologically different $X$. So the construction is not universal in sense of degree, but in each specified case it works.